# Keyset does not contain key while iterating

Tags: apex, debug

I am not sure how this is possible, but I keep getting null back as the value associated to a key as I iterate over a keyset...

```
List<Contact_Survey__c> contactSurveysToInsert = new List<contact_Survey__c>();
    for(Survey__c survey : surveyToPrimaryContactId.keySet()){
        System.debug('surveyToPrimaryContact.containsKey(survey):  '+ System.JSON.Serialize(surveyToPrimaryContactId.containsKey(survey)));
    }

19:42:21:477 USER_DEBUG [142]|DEBUG|surveyToPrimaryContact.containsKey(survey):  false
```

This doesn't make any sense to me... How can a keyset not contain its' members?

++Edit

Note that I poulate the keys (Survey__c objects) before I insert the survey__c records, but I know for a fact that he map has atleast one key value after the records are inserted and before I iterate over the keyset.

```
20:01:25:295 USER_DEBUG [129]|DEBUG|surveyToPrimaryContact: {"Survey__c:{Contact_Name__c=003m000000xwUmQAAU, Source_System__c=rForce, RecordTypeId=01261000000X3LyAAK, Store_Account__c=001m000000ekLUDAA2, Order_Name__c=801m00000022u1cAAA, Installation_Date__c=2018-04-26 00:00:00, Opportunity__c=006m0000008QDwmAAG, Enabled_Appointment_Id__c=null, Enabled_Lead_Id__c=null, Pivotal_Rn_AppointmentID__c=null, Primary_Contact_First_Name__c=Luke, Primary_Contact_Last_Name__c=Skywalker, Primary_Contact_Email__c=lskywalker@jedi.org, Primary_Contact_Home_Phone__c=111-222-3333, Primary_Contact_Work_Phone__c=null, Primary_Contact_Mobile_Phone__c=(444) 555-6666, State__c=Minnesota, City__c=Minneapolis, Country__c=United States, Street__c=1234 Main St, Zip__c=55418, Lead_Source__c=null, Secondary_Contact_First_Name__c=Han, Secondary_Contact_Last_Name__c=Solo, Secondary_Contact_email__c=hsolo@rebelalliance.com, Secondary_Contact_Home_Phone__c=(000) 999-8888, Secondary_Contact_Mobile_Phone__c=(777) 666-5555, Secondary_Contact_Work_Phone__c=null, Id=a2wm0000000B9o3AAC}":{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Contact/003m000000xwUmQAAU"},"Id":"003m000000xwUmQAAU","FirstName":"Luke","LastName":"Skywalker","Email":"lskywalker@jedi.org","HomePhone":"111-222-3333","Phone":null,"MobilePhone":"(444) 555-6666","MailingState":"Minnesota","MailingCity":"Minneapolis","MailingCountry":"United States","MailingStreet":"1234 Main St","MailingPostalCode":"55418"}}
```

Comment: How is your *surveyToPrimaryContactId* map declared and populated?

Comment: See above edits

Comment: Okay I see -- *before I insert the survey__c records* so you are inserting the record only after you have added it as the key in the map?

Comment: I just added details around considerations, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment above:

> Note that I poulate the keys (Survey__c objects) before I insert the survey__c records

This will not return the results as expected. Refer to excerpt from consideration (especially the highlighted ones) for using a SObject as key in map from official [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject_considerations.htm).

> **sObject Map Considerations**
>
> Be cautious when using sObjects as map keys. **Key matching for sObjects is based on the comparison of all sObject field values. If one or more field values change after adding an sObject to the map, attempting to retrieve this sObject from the map returns null**. This is because the modified sObject isn’t found in the map due to different field values. This can occur if you explicitly change a field on the sObject, or if the sObject fields are implicitly changed by the system; **for example, after inserting an sObject, the sObject variable has the ID field autofilled. Attempting to fetch this Object from a map to which it was added before the insert operation won’t yield the map entry**, as shown in this example.